# Is there an example to implement App.Metrics in ASP.NET Web API (not .net core)?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, metrics

I'm updating a ASP.NET Web API (.Net Framework 4.6.2) to include metrics using App.Metric nugets provided by the site below:

https://www.app-metrics.io/

Tried to run in a console app provided by the github site:

https://github.com/AppMetrics/Samples.V2

To make it work I had to do the following:

1. Remove all Nugets related to App.Metric from the solution
2. Remove all assemblies related to App.Metric
3. Add again the App.Metric nugets

Again, its easy to do in a console but I want an out-of-the-box generated endpoints similar to the Asp.Net Core examples.. is it possible to do the same with ASP.NET Web API framework version?

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Comment: I still didn't find a way to get this to work unfortunately

Answer (score 9):

You need to install [App.Metrics.Extensions.Owin.WebApi](https://www.nuget.org/packages/App.Metrics.Extensions.Owin.WebApi) nuget package and the follow this [sample code](https://github.com/AppMetrics/Samples/tree/master/src/Web.Api.Net452) to enable it on WebApi.